# Passing Data from custom tableview cell to UIView controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm following this [blog][1], for passing data from custom cell in a table view to a view controller. Custom cell is getting data from response and i have to show some of it in custom cell and rest of the data in Detail view controller. Can anybody identify where the actual problem is coming in my code? passing data from segue.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        //Do something
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.tites = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.prce = [_Price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.ara = [_LandArea objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.phon = [_Phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.citi = [_City objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.loc = [_location objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.tye = [_type objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.Idss = [_Id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.nam = [_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.emal = [_email objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.roomss = [_rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.wash = [_washroom objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.flloors = [_floor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.stat = [_status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.descrp = [_descrip objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.countryy = [_country objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

this is the error i'm facing when i click a cell.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key id.'  First throw call stack:

This is my [ShowViewcontroller.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1R0I.png) file.

changed code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXiMW.png)

Comment: What is your current output ?

Comment: How are you declaring Idss in ShowViewController ?

Comment: randomly given a name to access value. @AravindAR

Comment: no you might have declared Idss in ShowViewController right, just show its code

Comment: You have deleted any Outlet from from ShowViewController , check outlet properly

Comment: propid is my Label in UIVIEWController.@Dhiru

Comment: you to `stroryboard` select your viewController and right click on it , and see all outlet connection you must have connection with icon ⚠️ , remove this connection

Comment: after removing that and run it now getting this error,"-[StringData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000138b00
2017-07-03 15:41:20.922 PK.House[10411:854053] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StringData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000138b00'" .@Dhiru

Comment: now check my answer below ....only remove with that icon ,  and this must be your coding problem ,,, StringData is not correct which has lenght property @umer

Comment: how can i solve this? im not getting it. @Dhiru

Comment: dear , @umer you have solved your first problem ,  now you have encountred with another problem , you can accept and upvote answer and re-create an issue , or you can come on Private chat ,,,,  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144892/ios-dev-expert

Comment: i have not much reputation i cannot talk there.@Dhiru

Comment: ok, for the suggestion i'll tell you , create a break point and  and check which `StringData` objecte type its not an String ,,,, check and correct ,

Comment: okay,let me try.@Dhiru

Comment: Did not fine yet it. @Dhiru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have delete your `outlet` connection from `storyboard` to your `ViewController`
please check your outlet is connected properly or not. ⚠️

[image]

there must be an `id` property created first and delete by you , in your `showViewController`

Comment: its showing me this error now, -[StringData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000138b00
2017-07-03 15:41:20.922 PK.House[10411:854053] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StringData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000138b00'

Comment: `ShowViewController` in this  show your code , you can check now your ViewDidLoad is Calling of your `ShowViewController`

Answer (score 0):

**Check property in ShowViewController because destViewController.Idss (color is showing wrong)**

```
 @property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *Idss; // Make as this and 
 @synthesize Idss
```

**And also change [_Id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] // replace _id  Array name to with another name**

Comment: getting same error after making changes.@Lalit kumar

Comment: Ihave edited my question and added screen shot , check it out.@Lalit kumar